# Controls added to TabPage of the TabControl of my UserControl disappear after rebuild

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer, designer

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `TabControl`. I enabled the designer of the `TabControl` and its `TabPages` so the user can add/remove/modify tab pages and add controls to tab pages.

When I add my `UserControl` to the `Form` and add controls on tab pages it's OK and controls can be added/removed/changed properly until I build the project or save changes and close and reopen the form.

> When I build the project, every changes that I'd made in tab pages and each controls which I added to tab pages are removed. The controls exists on `designer.cs` but they doesn't show on tab pages.

Why do the controls I added to tab pages of the TabControl of my UserControl disappear after rebuild?

**My user control source code:**

Note: `tbBody` is a `TabControl`

```
[Designer(typeof(MainDesigner))]
public partial class MZTabControl : UserControl
{
    private bool isdesign = false;
    private bool allowtbodyresize = false;
    public MZTabControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [Category("MZ TabControl"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TabControl TabControlArea
    {
        get
        {
            return tbBody;
        }
    }
}
```

**My designer source code:**

```
public class MainDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    private DesignerVerbCollection dvc = new DesignerVerbCollection();
    public override void Initialize(System.ComponentModel.IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        if (this.Control is MZTabControl)
        {
            this.EnableDesignMode(((MZTabControl)this.Control).TabControlArea, 
                "TabControlArea");
            var uc = (MZTabControl)component;

            foreach (TabPage tbpg in uc.tbBody.TabPages)
            {
                EnableDesignMode(tbpg, tbpg.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before rebuild or clean: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ6KI.png)
After rebuild or clean: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZGy4.png)

Comment: You discovered the hard way that your [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute doesn't work.  If you want to serialize the content then the object must be serializable.  TabControl is not, none of the controls are.  So inevitably the content disappears again when the designer is reloaded.  It is very unclear why you like UserControl as the base class, you don't seem to be using multiple child controls.  Fall in the pit of success by derive your class from TabControl instead.

Comment: thank you hans passant, all vs components unclickable on design-time and only tabcontrol are clickable. i need a usercontrol with design-time click event. how i must serialize this tabcontrol?

Comment: TabControl already has a Click event, not a good enough reason to need UserControl as a base class.  Just call OnClick() to generate the event.

Comment: when i say clickable i mean its on design time clickable(when you design it on the form) for example one textbox one the usercontrol or a button or anything. but if i add a tabcontrol to the usercontrol and when i  use this usercontrol on my form with my mentioned steps its can click on design-time form(not design-time usercontrol), and you are right about using as a base class :)

Comment: Do you have a constant count of `TabPages` in your `TabControlArea` or pages should be added at design-mode?

Comment: @RezaAghaei temporary yes but what is different?

Comment: There is difference. If you have constant count of `TabPage` you can create public properties in your `UserControl` and enable designer of each tab page with name of corresponding property. But if the count of tab pages is not constant, the it's enough to start with a TabControl which has no tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer of `Form` cant't see those `TabPag` controls which you created in the `UserControl`.

You can remove all items from `TabPages` collection of the `TabControl` in your `UserControl`. If you need the `TabControl` have some pages after adding to `Form` you can add some tab pages in `InitializeNewComponent` method of designer of your user control. Then user can change those pages or add/remove pages to the `TabControl` of your `UserControl` and all tabs and their contents will be serialized because this way the `Form` designer can see those tabs.

**UserControl1**

Create a public property for the `TabControl` and decorate it with `DesignerSerializationVisibility` by passing `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` as value to say the designer serialize the content of control:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[Designer(typeof(UserControl1Designer))]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TabControl MyTabControl 
    {
       get { return this.tabControl1; } 
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Name = "UserControl1";
        this.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
}
```

**UserControl1Designer**

Enable the designer of `TabControl` using `EnableDesignMode` method of the designer. Also initialize the `TabControl` by adding 2 `TabPage` like the job that the original control performs. To do so, you should use `IDesignerHost` service like below.

```
public class UserControl1Designer : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override void Initialize(System.ComponentModel.IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);
        this.EnableDesignMode(((UserControl1)this.Control).MyTabControl, "MyTabControl");
    }
    public override void InitializeNewComponent(System.Collections.IDictionary values)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(values);
        AddTab();
        AddTab();
    }
    private void AddTab()
    {
        TabControl tabControl = ((UserControl1)this.Control).MyTabControl;
        var svc = (IDesignerHost)this.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        if (svc != null)
        {
            var tab1 = (TabPage)svc.CreateComponent(typeof(TabPage));
            tab1.Text = tab1.Name;
            tab1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab1);
            var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(tabControl)["Controls"];
            base.RaiseComponentChanging(property);
            base.RaiseComponentChanged(property, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you drag `UserControl1` from toolbox and add it to the form, you can see the user control contains an editable tab control which contains 2 editable tab pages and all changes will be serialized and be persisted.

### Note

If you have a single or two pages in the `TabContrl` of your `UserControl` and you want to make them editabe, you should create public properties in your `UserControl` and enable designer of each tab page with name of corresponding property.

Consider this note from remarks part of [`EnableDesignMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.enabledesignmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The child does not directly participate in persistence, but it will if
>   it is exposed as a property of the main control.

**UserControl**

You should have a public property for each `TabPage` which you want to expose:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public TabControl MyTabControl
{ 
    get { return this.tabControl1; } 
}
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public TabPage T1 
{
    get { return this.tabPage1; } 
}
```

**Designer**

```
public class MyUserControl2Designer : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override void Initialize(System.ComponentModel.IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);
        this.EnableDesignMode(((UserControl2)this.Control).MyTabControl, "MyTabControl");
        this.EnableDesignMode(((UserControl2)this.Control).T1, "T1");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i test your scenario but its not working :(
still disappears content.

Comment: I tested both approaches and both of them are working.

Comment: Delete existing user control from form1. Then close all designers, then clean and rebuild solution. Then put your user control on `Form1` which has no tab pages. Then in dsigner of `Form1` add tabpages and contents.  and save the form. Close and open the form again and you will see your content are serialized.

Comment: i add [Serializable] before MZTabControl class and when your solution its work :)

Comment: You don't need to add `[Serializable]` it's completely useless, because the control in not serializable. Use my example to see it works without `Serializable` attribute.

Comment: yes bro, your right :D
and if its constant, i must create a public property like TabControlArea?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an example for this case too.

Comment: Make sure you read the edit carefully. I added a feature to the designer of user control which allows you to initialize `TabControl` with some tab pages while they are editable.